# Writing complex numbers in polar form

Tags: complex-numbers

$z=4\mathrm{e}^{i1.7}$

Write the following numbers in the polar form $r\mathrm{e}^{i\phi}$:

a) $\bar{z}$

b) $\displaystyle \frac{1}{z}$

I need $r$ and $\phi$. I already have $r$ for the both of these (a is $4$, b is $.25$) but I'm not sure what $\phi$ is for either of them. I thought it would be $1.7$ for a and $1/1.7$ for b, but those are wrong. I'm also not sure what the bar over the $z$ in part (a) is.

Comment: Use that $z \times \overline{z} = |z|^2,~$ which is a real number.  Further, use (as an immediate consequence of the  definition of a conjugate) that $\overline{re^{i\theta}} = re^{-i\theta}.$

Answer (score 1):

The bar signifies that $\bar{z}$ is the conjugate of the complex number $z$. Conjugates of complex numbers are complex numbers with the same real part, but with the negative of their imaginary parts.

For example, if $z=3 + 4i$, $\bar{z}$ is $3-4i$.

That said, if you also know [how complex numbers are represented geometrically](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_plane#Notational_conventions), you should be able to use [Euler's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) to figure out what the angle is for a.

For b, you take take the reciprocal of z;

$\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{4e^{i1.7}}$

You're right about the value of r here. What do you think the value of $\phi$ would be if you simplify it into the standard polar form you've written of in your post?

---

Besides the links above, reading up on the basics of complex numbers should help.

Cheers!

Comment: I thought the phi answer in (b) would then be -1.7, but that wasn't correct either. I thought -1.7 would be the answer for (a) as well, but they were both wrong. I'm honestly lost here, my instructor hasn't gone over complex numbers yet.

Comment: @calicojack: I checked it with someone and I'm still pretty sure that's how it works out. Your book seems incorrect.